# Issues with promise chaining in firebase realtime database trigger

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise, google-cloud-functions

Stuck at promise chaining in my code below.

My realtime db has two nodes. users and orders. 
I have users where a reward amount is stored. i have a db trigger on orders when a new order is created. My requirement in the create trigger is to get the reward amount from the users node and deduct order amount then update new value back to users.

```
exports.on_order_received_deduct_doodle_cash = functions.database.ref("/orders/{id}")
.onCreate((change, context) => {

  const order = change.val();
  const customerObj = order.customer
  const orderObj = order.order
  const afterDiscount = orderObj._afterDiscount
  const uid = customerObj._uid

    var db = admin.database();
    const userRef = db.ref('users/')
    return userRef.child(uid).once("value").then(
        (resp) => {
              const userObj = resp.val()
              const doodleCash = userObj._doodleCash
              console.log("user current doodle cash is::" + doodleCash)
              return doodleCash
        }
    ).then(
        (doodleCash) => {

                if(doodleCash > afterDiscount){
                    const val = doodleCash - afterDiscount
                    return userRef.child(uid).update({"_doodleCash" : val})
                }else{
                    console.error("cannot be a negative value")
                    return null
                }

        }
    ).catch(
        (err) => console.error("something went wrong:" + err)
    )
})
```

is this the right way to pass the value from first promise to another?

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick.

You should return a promise in your first `then()` or a value that says to the platform that the Cloud Function is finished (like `null`).

```
exports.on_order_received_deduct_doodle_cash = functions.database.ref("/orders/{id}")
.onCreate((change, context) => {

  const order = change.val();
  const customerObj = order.customer
  const orderObj = order.order
  const afterDiscount = orderObj._afterDiscount
  const uid = customerObj._uid

    var db = admin.database();
    const userRef = db.ref('users/')
    return userRef.child(uid).once("value").then(
        (resp) => {
              const userObj = resp.val()
              const doodleCash = userObj._doodleCash
              console.log("user current doodle cash is::" + doodleCash)

              if (doodleCash > afterDiscount) {
                    const val = doodleCash - afterDiscount
                    return userRef.child(uid).update({"_doodleCash" : val})
                }else{
                    console.error("cannot be a negative value")
                    return null;
                }
        }
    ).catch(
        (err) => console.error("something went wrong:" + err)
    )
})
```

Comment: And is this the right or recommended way as well for this kind of situation?

Comment: Well... IMHO I think it is one of the right ways, this is why I wrote an answer!! :-)

Comment: hang on.. i was on mobile that time so did not read your response properly. your response is not then chaining. What i was looking for was how to do then chaining. As code gets messier if i end up doing something one more level deep based on previous crud on db.

Comment: any thoughts on my comment?

Comment: If you want to chain **Promises** I think you should return a Promise in each `then()`.

Comment: How will it look like it above case?  And do you recommend that if I have to go now than one level of work unlike above

Comment: IMHO, based on the code you shown in your question I recommend to go the way I shown in my answer. If you have other specific cases, I would recommend you ask another SO question.